# Writing to a File in Python: Out of Memory Exception

Tags: java, python, file, memory, pickle

I am trying to write a list to a file using pickle but I can not write except a limited size of it like the first 3000 items or so. Eech time I try to write the list fully I get this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This is the code I am using to do the job:

```
output = open('myfile.pkl', 'w')
pickle.dump(wells[:3000], output)
output.close()
```

Comment: Are you using Jython?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to increase your Java heap size.

Comment: Yep i agree, increase your JVM heap size

Comment: @StephenC should this be done through the code itself or OS spec.?

Answer (score 0):

Following are few options available to change Heap Size.

```
   -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
   -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
   -Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```